# Search and return nested values in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find

I have the following Data structure where `Question.findOne()` returns:

```
Object
_id: "8132c2f0-baee-434f-a739-c4d30718daf2"
owner: "273b7291-df2b-494c-bd9b-64e71283447e"
question: "Vacations?"
answers: Array[1]
  0: Object
  name: "Cancun"
  owned_by: "273b7291-df2b-494c-bd9b-64e71283447e"
  __proto__: Object
```

How can I `find` and `return` an array of answers from this document with `_id "8132c2f0-baee-434f-a739-c4d30718daf2"` using mongodb? Here is where I have started:

```
Questions.find({}, {"answers.name":1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Questions.findOne({_id:"8132c2f0-baee-434f-a739-c4d30718daf2"}, {answers:1});
```

Please also take a look at the docs:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields